# What Stripe webhook is used to capture subscription renewal when invoicing outside of Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I created a customer and subscription directly in the Stripe dashboard, as the customer is paying by check + invoicing outside of Stripe.

Stripe has been sending webhooks every month similarly to a normal credit card subscription, specifically the invoice webhooks (`invoice.updated`, `invoice.finalized`, `invoice.sent`), as well as `customer.subscription.updated`.

My app looks for the following webhooks to connect the billing events / actually upgrading the client's account:

```
customer.created
customer.subscription.created
customer.subscription.updated
customer.subscription.deleted
charge.succeeded
```

`charge.succeeded` has always been my go-to webhook to alert my app to update the client's account (e.g. supply the monthly benefit). My problem is that with invoicing, actually marking the invoice as "paid" lags 7-14 days behind the invoice generation and when the account is supposed to renew, so I can't use a `invoice.paid` as an equivalent to `charge.succeeded`.

I am trying to figure out what webhook is sent on the subscription renewal for a payment by check customer. `customer.subscription.updated` does happen upon subscription renewal, however that could be triggered on plan change. Same thing with `invoice.sent` -- that also could happen upon plan change.

Is there a webhook specifically for "this client's subscription just renewed, regardless of whether they paid already or not"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no event specifically for the renewal. What you should do is listen for `customer.subscription.updated` events and then look at the data that changed to assess whether it's a renewal or not. The idea is to look inside `data[previous_attributes]` ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data-previous_attributes)) on the `Event` and check whether the `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` properties have changed which would indicate a renewal (or a billing cycle change).

Comment: Thanks. I think `current_period_end` might be key here -- perhaps I will check and see if that date is between 26-36 days into the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer from here. It basically answers your question about stripe renewal webhook.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165193

Basically you can use the webhook 'invoice.payment_succeeded' and in its response look out for billing_reason.

If billing_reason == 'subscription_cycle' the webhook is for a subscription renewal.

If billing_reason == 'subscription_create' the webhook is for a brand new subscription.